# HP laptop file system check found a Toshiba device

Tags: filesystem, hp, fsck, toshiba

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Hp laptop and when I ran a file system check (fsck) it found a Toshiba device.

Answers on what this means would be highly appreciative.

Here is a screenshot: http://jmp.sh/v/ZHzq0FRxJzjAF4YTsc2O

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/products/toshiba-mk5061gsyn-hard-drive-500-gb-sata-3gb-s/specs/ You should try googling sometimes, much faster than ask and wait for answers.

Comment: Why is a Toshiba device showing up on a Hp laptop?

Comment: because Toshiba made the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Toshiba MK3261GSYN: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822149210 Either HP or a subsequent owner of the laptop installed the Toshiba drive. Your `fsck` result appears entirely normal.